# Load all JSF components in a page as Texts conditionally

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

It is required in my JSF2 (with Facelets) application to have many pages open in ReadOnly/Editable mode. Following is the exact behavior required:

1. The page first loads in ReadOnly mode when all the page components
   are displayed as texts.
2. User clicks on Edit button to open the page in Editable mode.
3. In Editable mode, all the components are visible and can be manipulated.
4. User makes changes and clicks on Save, which loads the page back in ReadOnly mode (i.e. all texts and no components).

If I have a TextArea on the page, In ReadOnly mode I do not want to make it disabled/readOnly, I want an outputText instead. In Editable mode it should behave as TextArea.

What would be a suitable way of accomplishing this, considering I need this behavior on multiple pages in the application.

Shall I write two components (textArea and outputText) and manipulate their rendered property to display one.

Is it possible to somehow control the behavior of elements on JSF and render Texts instead of the components themselves (maybe by writing custom Renderer)?

Thanks a lot in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for their inputs... :-)
Hi Found out a way to make it work in a different way. I had to write the following:

1. A Custom tag: All the elements falling inside this TAG would have the Read/Write behavior
2. A Custom Renderer: Which would render all the textboxes, dropdowns etc on the page if they fall under the custom tag.

Here is my XHTML

```
    <rw:readWrite readOnlyOn="#{!rwBean.editMode}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Booking Center P" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="bookingCentre" value="#{rwBean.bookingCenter}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{rwBean.bookingCenterList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel value="Account Number 1" />
            <h:inputText id="accountNumber1" value="987654" maxlength="7" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rw:readWrite>
```

Based on the value of the attribute "readOnlyOn", my custom tag would set an attribute in each of its child components.
My custom renderer would check the value of this attribute on the tag and render the tag itself or its "value" attribute conditionally.

I have implemented this for all the JSF and PrimeFaces tags and it seems to work for me.

Comment: If I use your approach, I would have to write many custom tags (one for inputText, one for SelectOne etc.), But using this approach, I just wrote two classes (One for Component and one for Renderer). All the components would be rendered by the same Custom Renderer, which would conditionally choose to render the component itself (if in read mode) or delegate the rendering to respective Renderer (if in edit mode).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a composite component or a tag file so that you end up like this:

```
<my:inputTextArea editable="#{bean.editable}" />
```

which contains in case of a composite component basically

```
<h:inputTextArea rendered="#{cc.attrs.editable}" />
<h:outputText rendered="#{!cc.attrs.editable}" />
```

or in case of a tag file

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{editable}"><h:inputTextArea /></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><h:outputText /></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```